# how to set name for drop zone area in dropzone?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, laravel

I am using Laravel blade, I am facing problem that am not able to get the input name for dropzone area to save to the database in `dropzone.js`. So I need to set name for dropzone area which must be type `array`.

Below is my code.

```
{!!Form::model(null,array('url'=>'/assets/global/plugins/dropzone/upload.php','class'=> 'dropzone dropzone-file-area', 'id'=> 'my-dropzone','files'=>'true','style'=>"width: 100%;height:50px;")) !!}
<h3 class="sbold">**Drop files here or click to upload**</h3>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `'id'=> 'my-dropzone'` from `Form::model()` and put it in div inside the form:

```
<div id="my-dropzone"></div>
```

Comment: I've described the correct approach. Use the code from my answer and try to find out why Dropzone doesn't work. Please describe show errors you get (check browser Console, Laravel log, Apache log etc).

Comment: If I put it in div means that dropzone area itself is not showing. Only If I put in form tag means it will show.

Comment: If you have source code means please post it that's makes lots easier.